# Uiscrollview not able to add uilabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to add uilabels to a uiscrollview. I use a for loop to create 20 labels and then add them one by one in the scroll view. Does no work. Here is my code

```
-(void)setScrollViews{
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) 
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20 * i,160 , 30)];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label number %d", i ];
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        [label sizeToFit];
        [self.activitiesScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, self.activitiesScrollView.frame.size.height + 20)];
        [self.activitiesScrollView addSubview:label];
        [self.view addSubview:self.activitiesScrollView];
   }
}
```

I am using storyboard. I also tried `alloc init` but it still failed. I did set the delegate in the `viewdidload`. I changed the background image for the scrollview to check if it is there on the screen and it is.

EDIT:This works now, All I did was restart Xcode

Comment: Where you invoke `setScrollViews` method?

Comment: Can you post that part also? Are you allocating activitiesScrollView? If you are using storyboard why are you adding activitiesScrollView as subview in self.view. rather you can place in xib right?

Comment: check your xib file to see if `activitiesScrollView` outlet is connect.

Comment: @user3097889 the adding subview part was a desperate attempt to get this to work :(

Comment: @johnMa outlet is connected

Comment: Your code is working fine for me..I didn't add this line         [self.view addSubview:self.activitiesScrollView];. I included activitiesScrollView in XIB.
. You may need to check any other view is added on top of the scrollview.

Comment: Restarted my Xcode, suddenly it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this . . .

you are adding scrollview 20 times to the uiview in the loop . that is also wrong part of your code

```
-(void)setScrollViews{

    [self.view addSubview:self.activitiesScrollView];

    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) 
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20 * i,160 , 30)];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label number %d", i ];
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        [label sizeToFit];
        [self.activitiesScrollView addSubview:label];
        [self.activitiesScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, self.activitiesScrollView.frame.size.height + 20)];

   }
}
```

Comment: I don't get this. 1. you are adding the label before you alloc it, 2even if that worked, this code would only increase the size of the scrollview. Or am i missing something?

Comment: it was a mistake ... now check this

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
-(void)setScrollViews{
        for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) 
        {
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20 * i,160 , 30)];
            label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
            label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label number %d", i ];
            label.numberOfLines = 0;
            [label sizeToFit];
            [self.activitiesScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, self.activitiesScrollView.frame.size.height + 20)];
            [self.activitiesScrollView addSubview:label];
       }
      [self.view addSubview:self.activitiesScrollView];

    }
```